# use tensorflow object detection API for gender recognition

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, face-detection, object-detection-api

can I use tensorflow object detection API for gender recognition?
I want to train SSD_mobile net for gender recognition and detection. I changed labelmap to:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'man'
}
item {
  id: 2
  name: 'woman'
}
```

and num_classes=2
I attach to training_loss=8 but when I feed an image to the network to test, the result is awful. 
what should I do? can somebody help me?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841927/tensorflow-object-detection-api-for-object-detection-but-the-result-is-not-good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of task you will need a huge dataset and a very long time for training if you don't have a super computer haha jokes apart but this is pretty difficult we need very keen analysis because men or women has almost same kind of features for computer not for us  but for computer just like it can not make a difference between a bitch and a dog but we human can by just one watch so I hope you will understand what I am trying to say but you should definitely try it its a very nice idea and there is a lot of applications for this if you can do some thing better with this. Good luck let me know if you can do some thing better.

Comment: Yeah, Its exactly right. We are training the network for IMDB dataset for 40000 iteration. We have acheived good results for images which contains only one face , but for images which have more than one face its baaad. I think IMDB has basic problems , So we should find a better dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can. The method that you need to follow is as following:

- Use SSD to extract the location of the object to be found (face in here).
- Get relevant feature map of the location at conv5 (assume that you use VGG). For example, if you find your object at location (100, 100, 100, 100 - XYWH) within input image with size (300, 300), cut conv5 features at (12, 12, 12, 12 - XYWH). Math is (100 / 300) * 38.
- Now you shall have the activation features cut from conv5 (12 x 12 x 512) and which is only relevant with the face that you want to predict the gender.
- Flatten this feature activation and apply DNN Classifier for it (i.e. Classifier used for VGG).
- Get binary output stating either male or female.
- Train your network by adding gender loss to global loss function.

Voila. You have the gender estimation network.